# Image Alignment HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to bring the delete and edit buttons on one line and the text on next line.
Unable to figure it out.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <strong><%= comment.author.username%></strong>
    <span class="pull-right">10 days ago</span>
    <p>
      <a id="myImg" href="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%= comment._id%>/edit">
        <img width="10" height="10" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/59/59399.png">
      </a>

      <form class="delete-form" action="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%= comment._id%>/?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <input width="10" height="10" type="image" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/25-free-ui-icons/40/trash_bin-128.png"></input>
      </form>
      <%=comment.text%>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which text?! Can you explain what you need to do?

Comment: The Images sourced here are icons corresponding to DELETE and EDIT and there is a text that is DELETED and EDITED

Comment: Currently Viewed as:
o - > icon for edit
x -> icon for delete
abc -> text

I want to view it as like this:
o x
abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <strong>Username</strong>
    <span class="pull-right">10 days ago</span>
    <div>
      <form class="delete-form" action="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%= comment._id%>/?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <a id="myImg" href="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%= comment._id%>/edit">
          <img width="10" height="10" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/59/59399.png">
        </a>


        <input width="10" height="10" type="image" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/25-free-ui-icons/40/trash_bin-128.png"></input>
      </form>
      Comment text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works Perfectly FIne

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <strong><%= comment.author.username%></strong>
                <span class="pull-right">10 days ago</span>
<div style="display:block">                    

                 <a id="myImg" href="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%= comment._id%>/edit"> 
                    <img width="10" height="10" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/59/59399.png">
                 </a>

                    <form class="delete-form" action="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%= comment._id%>/?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                       <input width="10" height="10" type="image" src = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/25-free-ui-icons/40/trash_bin-128.png"></input>
                    </form>
</div>
<div style="display:block">
                        <%=comment.text%>
</div>

                </div>
           </div>
```